# Copy content and bring url

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When copy any content from a webpage and paste it in a different app I need to bring the URL.

### Example:

I have a URL **http://example.com** and in the page I have a paragraph that says *This is my content*.

1. The user go to that URL
2. User select the paragraph > right click > copy
3. User go to the notepad > right click > paste
4. The content pasted in notepad should be **This is my content brought from http://example.com/test**
5. The link should be clickable

Any suggestion of a tool that can help me to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Comment: Last time I tried changing clipboard data from Chrome I failed. May be try creating an addon or an extension for Chrome browser which does this? Meaning copy selected line and add url information to it? Not sure even if that is possible.

Comment: Hi @LearningEveryday thank you! unfortunately I can't use any extension for this project... How ever I already saw another website doing it.... I'm sure its something very simple! but I can't find a way to do it. without interpolating a hard-coded a tag to my clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `copy` event handler:

```
document.addEventListener('copy', function(event) {
  var text = window.getSelection().toString() + " brought from http://example.com/test";
  event.clipboardData.setData('text/html', text);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

You can't guarantee the link is clickable, that depends on where you are pasting the text.

Comment: Thank you @ariel It became clickable once I replaced the argument 'text/plain' for 'text/html'

Answer (score 0):

Try using this : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-copy/bijpdibkloghppkbmhcklkogpjaenfkg

Its an extension! I will give it a try now as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. For the url to be clickable part, in default Windows notepad app, url's cannot be clickable as I know. But other apps like Notepad++, Microsoft Word.. url's are clickable already.

```js
document.addEventListener("copy", function(event){
  var select = document.getSelection();
  event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', "-Brought to you by G.E.V.: "+select.toString());
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<div>Gev gev gev gev</div>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Paste here to test.."></textarea>
```